# Changing images in Imageview

Tags: android

I am changing images in Imageview after every 5 sec with a bit of animation to show the transition.However the animation is very simple and i want a good animation.Can anyone give me a some decent animation code that I can use in my app.
Here is the code

```
public class Sampledslr extends Activity {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    int count;
    int images[] = { R.drawable.ds8, 
            R.drawable.mr1,
            R.drawable.mr3, 
            R.drawable.mr4,
            R.drawable.mr6, 
            R.drawable.mr3,
            R.drawable.mr7 };
    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sampledslr);
         imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

         //imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
        //imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        handler.postDelayed(changeImage, 7000);
    }
    Runnable changeImage = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (count >6) {
                handler.removeCallbacks(changeImage);
            } else {

                if (count >= 6)
                    count = 0;
                AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.5f, 1.0f); //here is a bit of animation for ya ;)
                animation1.setDuration(5000);
                animation1.setStartOffset(1000); //time for that color effect
                animation1.setFillAfter(true);
                imageView.startAnimation(animation1);
                imageView.setImageResource(images[count++]);
                handler.postDelayed(changeImage, 7000);
                }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Can anyone suggest a good animation.` - This is not how StackOverflow works.

Comment: Can you please give me the code of some decent animations that i can implement in my code?

Answer (score 0):

The best option is create a xml file into res/anim and and then assign it to imageview.

Examples animations in xml:

**anim_clockwise**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1"
        android:duration="350" >
    </alpha>

</set>
```

**anim_rotate**

```
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="1000"/>
```

**slide_out_left**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-50%p"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

**slide_out_right**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

*Example put animation into imageview*

```
private Animation mAnimationSplash;
```

.
.
.

```
private void animImage() {

        mAnimationSplash = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_clockwise);
        mImageView.setAnimation(mAnimationSplash);

    }
```

Comment: Can you put the error here? The error that show in the Android Monitor

Comment: I am using it inside runnable's run function.When i use it inside oncreate it works fine,but i want to use it inside runnable.

Comment: Sorry then, sure it's silly, I will try to investigate why that happens :)

Comment: Ok,btw thnxx for giving the answer.

Comment: you are welcome, I hope you serve for future applications!